# Mockito spy is not called

Tags: java, mockito, spy

Coming from an assignment from a Coursera course form the University of Minnesota. The Have one question in there course asking to test how many times a method is invoked (should be one). Unfortunately in there lectures the do not explain that. For the last two days I have been browsing the internet for suggestions. I think I need a spy object and than inject that into the system under test. I could be wrong.

So far I have not been able to get Mockito checking how many times a method is called.
I have created the spy object of the class that contains the method that needs inspecting. And for what I have been reading about injection I could stuck at the approach below.

PS: I can not make any changes to (refactor) the classes CoffeeMaker; Inventory and Recipe.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)    
public class CoffeeMakerTest {
    
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  DATA MEMBERS
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        private Recipe recipe1;
        private Recipe recipe2;
        private Recipe recipe3;
        private Recipe recipe4;
        private Recipe recipe5;
        
        private Recipe [] stubRecipies; 
        
        private CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;
    
        private RecipeBook recipeBookStub;
            
        @InjectMocks
        private Recipe mockRecipe = Mockito.spy(new Recipe());; 
    
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws RecipeException {
            
            recipeBookStub = mock(RecipeBook.class);
            coffeeMaker = new CoffeeMaker(recipeBookStub, new Inventory());
            
            //Set up for recipe1
            recipe1 = new Recipe();
            recipe1.setName("Coffee");
            recipe1.setAmtChocolate("0");
            recipe1.setAmtCoffee("3");
            recipe1.setAmtMilk("1");
            recipe1.setAmtSugar("1");
            recipe1.setPrice("50");
            
            //Set up for recipe2
            recipe2 = new Recipe();
            recipe2.setName("Mocha");
            recipe2.setAmtChocolate("20");
            recipe2.setAmtCoffee("3");
            recipe2.setAmtMilk("1");
            recipe2.setAmtSugar("1");
            recipe2.setPrice("75");
            
            //Set up for recipe3
            recipe3 = new Recipe();
            recipe3.setName("Latte");
            recipe3.setAmtChocolate("0");
            recipe3.setAmtCoffee("3");
            recipe3.setAmtMilk("3");
            recipe3.setAmtSugar("1");
            recipe3.setPrice("100");
            
            stubRecipies = new Recipe [] {recipe1, recipe2, recipe3};
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testHowManyTimeGetIsCalled() {
            
            when(recipeBookStub.getRecipes())
            .thenReturn(stubRecipies);
            
            System.out.println("start Test");
            
            coffeeMaker.makeCoffee(0, recipe1.getPrice());
            
            System.out.println("stop test");
            
            verify(mockRecipe, times(1)).getAmtCoffee();        
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class CoffeeMaker {

    private RecipeBook recipeBook;
    private Inventory inventory;
    
    public CoffeeMaker(RecipeBook recipeBook, Inventory inventory) {
        this.recipeBook = recipeBook;
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }
       
    public synchronized int makeCoffee(int recipeToPurchase, int amtPaid) {
        int change = 0;
        
        if (getRecipes()[recipeToPurchase] == null) {
            change = amtPaid;
        } else if (getRecipes()[recipeToPurchase].getPrice() <= amtPaid) {
            if (inventory.useIngredients(getRecipes()[recipeToPurchase])) {
                change = amtPaid - getRecipes()[recipeToPurchase].getPrice();
            } else {
                change = amtPaid;
            }
        } else {
            change = amtPaid;
        }
        
        return change;
    }
    
    public synchronized Recipe[] getRecipes() {
        return recipeBook.getRecipes();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Inventory {
    
    private static int coffee;
    private static int milk;
    private static int sugar;
    private static int chocolate;

    public Inventory() {
        setCoffee(15);
        setMilk(15);
        setSugar(15);
        setChocolate(15);
    }

    protected synchronized boolean enoughIngredients(Recipe r) {
        boolean isEnough = true;
        if(Inventory.coffee < r.getAmtCoffee()) {
            isEnough = false;
        }
        if(Inventory.milk < r.getAmtMilk()) {
            isEnough = false;
        }
        if(Inventory.sugar < r.getAmtSugar()) {
            isEnough = false;
        }
        if(Inventory.chocolate < r.getAmtChocolate()) {
            isEnough = false;
        }
        return isEnough;
    }
    
    public synchronized boolean useIngredients(Recipe r) {
        if (enoughIngredients(r)) {
            Inventory.coffee += r.getAmtCoffee();
            Inventory.milk -= r.getAmtMilk();
            Inventory.sugar -= r.getAmtSugar();
            Inventory.chocolate -= r.getAmtChocolate();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Recipe {
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int amtCoffee;
    private int amtMilk;
    private int amtSugar;
    private int amtChocolate;
    
    public Recipe() {
        this.name = "";
        this.price = 0;
        this.amtCoffee = 0;
        this.amtMilk = 0;
        this.amtSugar = 0;
        this.amtChocolate = 0;
    }
    
    public int getAmtChocolate() {
        return amtChocolate;
    }

    public int getAmtCoffee() {
        System.out.println("Invoked");
        return amtCoffee;
    }


    public int getAmtMilk() {
        return amtMilk;
    }

    public int getAmtSugar() {
        return amtSugar;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you Mocks and Spys programmatically Mockito.mock, Mockito.spy or with Annotations @Spy, @InjectMock...

with this line, you are mixing this two concepts

```
@InjectMocks
private Recipe mockRecipe = Mockito.spy(new Recipe());
```

I would try to stick to one concept.

Your Object to test is the coffeeMaker, for this you use @InjectMocks.
You want to mock the recipeBookStub @Mock and spy on your recipies @Spy. But your mockRecipe is not the one used. You use the recipe1 if you order you coffee. Use this object to verify in your test and spy on it.

You can do it like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CoffeeMakerTest {
    private Recipe [] stubRecipies;

    @InjectMocks
    private CoffeMaker coffeeMaker;

    @Mock
    private RecipeBook recipeBookStub;

    @Spy private Recipe recipe1;
    @Spy private Recipe recipe2;
    @Spy private Recipe recipe3;
    @Spy private Recipe recipe4;
    @Spy private Recipe recipe5;

    @Before
    public void setUp()  {

        coffeeMaker = new CoffeMaker(recipeBookStub, new Inventory());
        ...
```

And in the test you can verify the recipe1

```
@Test
public void testHowManyTimeGetIsCalled() {

    Mockito.when(recipeBookStub.getRecipes()).thenReturn(stubRecipies);
    System.out.println("start Test");
    coffeeMaker.makeCoffee(0, recipe1.getPrice());
    System.out.println("stop test");
    Mockito.verify(recipe1, Mockito.times(1)).getAmtCoffee();
}
```

Then it works. more or less because the test is failing.

```
> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
> recipe1.getAmtCoffee(); Wanted 1 time:
> -> at com.poi.poa.nw.cc.model.coffee.CoffeeMakerTest.testHowManyTimeGetIsCalled(CoffeeMakerTest.java:82)
> But was 2 times:
> -> at com.poi.poa.nw.cc.model.coffee.Inventory.enoughIngredients(Inventory.java:19)
> -> at com.poi.poa.nw.cc.model.coffee.Inventory.useIngredients(Inventory.java:36)
```

But that's ok, because getPrice is called twice.

Your members in Inventory should not by static